# How does Jsoup make jQuery like selectors?

Tags: java, jsoup, selector

I've used jsoup in the past and I can't seem to understand how the jquery like selectors are being defined. I've read the source code and I still can't understand.

```
public static final class ContainsOwnText extends Evaluator {
        private String searchText;

        public ContainsOwnText(String searchText) {
            this.searchText = searchText.toLowerCase();
        }

        @Override
        public boolean matches(Element root, Element element) {
            return (element.ownText().toLowerCase().contains(searchText));
        }

        @Override
        public String toString() {
            return String.format(":containsOwn(%s", searchText);
        }
    }
```

The above can be called like this

```
select("*:containsOwn("+ str + ")");
```

[Here is the select](https://github.com/jhy/jsoup/blob/master/src/main/java/org/jsoup/select/Selector.java)

Questions:

Can someone explain to me how the ContainsOwn works?

> ---

```
return String.format(":containsOwn(%s", searchText);
```

Why the above is not like this?

```
return String.format(":containsOwn(%s)", searchText);
```

[And here is the evaluator](https://github.com/jhy/jsoup/blob/master/src/main/java/org/jsoup/select/Evaluator.java)

I'm asking because I want to understand how jsoup works, it's not I'm having a trouble making it work. I just want to know how it's done. If I wanted to replicate this behavior with the jquery-like selectors and wanted to develop something similar what should I do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you call `select(query)` that query is parsed to populate a set of evaluators, which are then passed to the Collector to construct a set of elements that satisfy the query.

In this case the [QueryParser](https://github.com/jhy/jsoup/blob/master/src/main/java/org/jsoup/select/QueryParser.java) on line 162 the `containsOwn` operation causes the `contains` method on line 325 to be called, which creates an instance of `ContainsOwn` evaluator.

This evaluator is passed to the [`Collector`](https://github.com/jhy/jsoup/blob/master/src/main/java/org/jsoup/select/Collector.java) that traverses the tree calling the `matches` method of each evaluator. In this case (in `ContainsOwn`) the `matches` method uses the `contains` method of `java.lang.String` to check if the given string is contained within the own text of the element.

The `toString` method in `ContainsOwn` has been written to mirror the syntax used to create it and has no effect on how it is created (this is dealt with by the QueryParser). The lack of a closed parenthesis looks like a harmless typo.