# jsoup css selector: escape question mark

Tags: java, css-selectors, jsoup

Given a tag with class containing question mark

```
<h2 class="?class-text ">mark-text should be blue</h2>
```

How do I select it with jsoup selector?

I tried

```
doc.select("h2.\\?class-text")
doc.select("h2.?class-text")
doc.select("h2[class=?class-text]")
doc.select("h2[class=\\?class-text]")
```

but none of these works.

This one works

```
doc.select("h2[class*=class-text]")
```

but I want to select exact match.

[JSFiddle for this](http://jsfiddle.net/55b02dy0/)

UPD:

```
doc.select("h2[class~=\\?class-text]")
```

worked. But is there solution without regex?

Comment: That's not regex. In fact, that's an invalid selector due to the stray `.` in the middle of the selector.

Comment: Also, you can't run Java code in JSFiddle, so that fiddle is quite pointless. The CSS selector in that fiddle is equivalent to `doc.select("h2.\\?class-text")` in your Java code, which according to you does not work; yet, the fiddle works.

Comment: Oops, dots between h2 and [class=] are placed by mistake. I've edited the post. According to http://jsoup.org/cookbook/extracting-data/selector-syntax it IS regex: "[attr~=regex]: elements with attribute values that match the regular expression"

Comment: Wow, so it looks like jsoup took an existing selector and repurposed it. In standard CSS it's not regex and there are no regex-based selectors.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to use `select` then what you are passing as an argument will be eventually treated as a regex. The string you pass is actually passed in `matches` method of `String` (this is an oversimplification of what it actually does, but you get the idea). 
[Check this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17335386/how-jsoup-makes-jquery-like-selectors) . If you don't want to use regular expressions then use this:

```
import org.jsoup.Jsoup;
import org.jsoup.nodes.Document;
import org.jsoup.select.Elements;

public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try {
            String str = "<div><h2 class=\"?class-text \">mark-text should be blue</h2></div>"; 
            Document doc = Jsoup.parse(str);

            Elements el = doc.getElementsByClass("?class-text");
            System.out.println(el);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I didn't know that all selectors use regex inside. I'll use ~= selector then, because sometimes I need to select several classes with one selector